# Golang register finalizer for underlying slice data

Tags: go, garbage-collection, finalizer

My goal is to get a callback whenever the underlying data of a buffer isn't referenced anywhere and should therefore be eligible for GC. I'm trying to implement this functionality by registering a [finalizer](https://pkg.go.dev/runtime#SetFinalizer) on top of a buffer.

In the code snippet below, for every iteration, I'm creating some buffer and for each created buffer, I'm registering a finalizer. The buffer is appended to an array of buffers.

The problem in that code, is that if the callee (`main` function in that case) calls `*` on the return value of `makeSlice`, the finalizer will get called even though the underlying data will not get GCed.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "runtime"
    "time"
)

func finalizer(_ *[]byte) {
    fmt.Println("finalize is called")
}

// makeSlice generates a buffer and register a finalizer.
func makeSlice() *[]byte {
    buffer := []byte(fmt.Sprintf("some info"))
    runtime.SetFinalizer(&buffer, finalizer)
    return &buffer
}

func main() {

    var buffers [][]byte
    for i := 0; i < 10000; i++ {
        buffers = append(buffers, *makeSlice())
    }
    // run some GC and wait a little.
    runtime.GC()
    time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)

    // do something with the buffers so that they don't get GC by the previous call
    var m byte
    for _, buffer := range buffers {
        if (buffer)[0] > m {
            m = (buffer)[0]
        }
    }
    fmt.Println(m)
}
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to get a callback when the underlying data of the buffer is to get GCed

Thanks

Comment: I'd recommend not doing that: 1) a finalizer makes the object it's set on actually miss the GC round which has found the object (refer to the SetFinalizer docs); 2) a finalizer may not run at all because an object might not get collected for various reasons. It would be interesting to hear about the original problem you're trying to solve using finalizers to rule out the possibility of [an XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/). For instance, if you'd want to implement pooled objects, that's not how you should approach such a task.

Comment: Register a finalizer for the backing array instead of the slice: `runtime.SetFinalizer(&buffer[0], finalizer)`.

Comment: To expand on what I've written, finalizers have very narrow scope of applicability. Basically it's freeing precious system resources (such as opened files/sockets) and debugging complex cases of shared objects getting freed when they should have been not.

Comment: @kostix, as you guessed, the original problem is pool related. We're exposing some buffers, and we now want to be notified when they're not in use anymore. The problem is that it requires lots of changes to have the callee calling `pool.Put` so I'm trying to see if the buffer can be "recycled" thru finalizer.

Comment: It's not clear that pooling from a finalizer provides any value given that the GC has already done the work to discover that the value is not referenced.

Comment: OK, I see. Still, I'd recommend to think again ;-) The way finalizers work—a finalizer is run by the nearest GC pass which found the object—mean the objects to be pooled are kept afloat for too long before being returned to the pool ASAP—basically, the most wanted property of pooling: if you're OK with such "freed" (as in "without references") objects floating around as garbage, you do not probably need pooling in the first place. Please keep in mind that a GC pass is not required to find all possible garbage; IOW, you cannot rely on the fact your objects will be processed "soon enough".